# How can I insert image name in database in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, insert, save

So far I have implemented is done below.

The problem that I am facing is i cannot update the file name and as a result I am getting an error, resulting the file from not being upload.

Controller:

```
public function add(){ 
    if (!empty($this->data)) {  
        if (!empty($this->data['Note'])){  
            $filename = basename($this->data['Note']['note_image']['name']); 
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['Note']['note_image']['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . $filename); 

            if($this->Note->save($this->data['Note'])){  
                $this->Session->setFlash('The note has been saved');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
            }           
        }  
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Note', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('note_title');
echo $this->Form->input('note_desc');
echo $this->Form->input('note_image', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add');
?>
```

I think save function will not be there. Is there a way to do it.

Comment: "I am getting an error" - the error should be in the question. Also please tag your question with the version of CakePHP you are using (looks like 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

**Code For Controller Should be like this :**

```
public function add(){ 
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {  
            $file = $this->request->data['Note']['note_image']; 
            if($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
            {
                $filename = $file['name']; 
                if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . $filename))
                {
                    $this->request->data['Note']['note_image'] = $filename;
                    if($this->Note->save($this->request->data)){  
                        $this->Session->setFlash('The note has been saved');
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('ERROR');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
            }              
        }  
    }
```

**View Should be like this :**

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Form->create('Note', array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
echo $this->Form->input('note_title');
echo $this->Form->input('note_desc');
echo $this->Form->input('note_image', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add');
?>
```

Comment: Dear I thought your post will be useful, but I am getting an error saying: 'Fatal error: Call to a member function is() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\cake\app\controllers\notes_controller.php on line 34'. Do you have any other solution. But still I would thank you for a try.

Comment: try this : if ($this->request->is('post')

Comment: this is for cakephp 2.x version